# Data set with mixed Date formats

Tags: r, date, format

I downloaded some financial time series and realized that for some reason the Dates are having a mixed format, such as for instance:

"01/28/2013" "01/29/2013" "01/30/2013" "01/31/2013" "41276"      "41366"
[985] "41396"      "41427"      "41457"      "41488"      "41580"      "41610"
[991] "02/13/2013" "02/14/2013" "02/15/2013" "02/19/2013" "02/20/2013" "02/21/2013"
[997] "02/22/2013" "02/25/2013" "02/26/2013" "02/27/2013"

I know that if I try convertToDate("41396") for instance, it will convert this 5-digit number to the correct Date, but the same command applied to a correct-format Date converts it into a NA.

Does someone know any other way how to deal with this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably best to see if you can fix this at the source of the data.
In your example there are two formats ("MM/DD/YYYY" and 5 digits which is the excel format). If those are the only two formats you could easily capture those with text processing (regex) and then convert to a uniform date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
dates <- c("01/28/2013", "01/29/2013", "01/30/2013", "01/31/2013", "41276", "41366", 
           "41396", "41427", "41457", "41488", "41580", "41610") 

dplyr::coalesce(
  as.Date(as.numeric(dates), origin = "1899-12-30"),
  as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
  )
```

Result

```
 [1] "2013-01-28" "2013-01-29" "2013-01-30" "2013-01-31" "2013-01-02"
 [6] "2013-04-02" "2013-05-02" "2013-06-02" "2013-07-02" "2013-08-02"
[11] "2013-11-02" "2013-12-02"
```